# Open iOS mail attachment directly in app bypassing "Open in..." menu

Tags: ios, swift

My app defines a custom document type and when I tap on an attachment my app appears in the "Open in..." menu however I was wondering if it was possible to not show this menu at all but rather open the file immediately in the app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, not possible. You have no control over what the Mail app shows to the user when an attachment is selected. The Mail app, like many other apps, uses a `UIActivityViewController` to give the user lots of other choices. Opening the attachment in your app is only one possible action a user may want to perform on the email attachment.

Comment: Thank you. This is what I suspected.

If I wanted to accomplish something similar perhaps a Universal Link could work?

Comment: You could add a link in the email body. Use your app's custom URL scheme in the URL. That would be the best way to allow the user to directly launch your app from an email. But this wouldn't bring along the attachment.